# there is some problems in this python phonebook program

Tags: python

I want to write a python program, but when i input s or S, it goes wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

phonebook = {}

while True:
    option = raw_input('Welcome use pyphonebook: add(A) / search(S)?')
    if option == 'A' or 'a':
        print 'Add a contact'
        name = raw_input('Enter a name:')
        if phonebook.__contains__(name):    
            print 'Contact %s is already in phonbook' % name
        else:
            num = raw_input('Enter phone number:')
        phonebook[name] = num

elif option == 'S' or 's':  
    print 'Search a contact'
    name = raw_input('Enter a name:')
    if name in phonebook:
        print "%s's phone number is %s" % (name, phonebook[name])
    else:
        print 'Not found'       
print phonebook
```

When i input S or s, it print 'Add a contact'. Why?

Comment: Is that how your `elif` is indented in your actual code? At the same level as `while`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test:

```
if option == 'A' or 'a':
```

is actually working like this:

```
if (option == 'A') or 'a':
```

As 'a' is always True, this test always passes.

You want instead

```
if (option == 'A') or (option == 'a')
```

or

```
if option in ('A', 'a'):
```

Answer (score 2):

You are testing for the wrong thing, use:

```
if option.lower() == 'a':
```

or perhaps:

```
if option in ('A', 'a'):
```

The expression `option == 'A' or 'a'` is interpreted as:

```
(option == 'A') or 'a'
```

and a non-empty string is always considered `True` in python.

Answer (score 0):

if `a == 7 or 5`  does not mean if `a == 7 or if a == 5`
it means `(a==7) or 5`  since 5 is non falsey it always is true

same thing with your comparison only its 'A' and 'a' instead of 7 and 5....